# ASP.NET Gridview OnUpdating event not updating decimal value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 gridview control with template fields for updating/inserting/displaying values from a 3-column table.  Thus there's an onUpdating event wired in to handle the update.

My problem is that the decimal column doesn't update when I enter a 0, 0.0 or other permutations of 0.  Works fine with positive or negative values, and the other visible column DOES update.  Also, inserting new rows with 0 on the decimal field doesn't seem to have a problem.

How can I fix this?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="PriceGroupGv" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="PriceGroupEds" DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
         ShowHeader="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" ShowFooter="true" ItemType="Infrastructure.PricingGroup"
         CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="GhostWhite" OnRowUpdating="PriceGroupGv_RowUpdating">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Markup</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NameTxt" runat="server" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NameTxt" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg" ForeColor="Red">
                            *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MarkupTxt" runat="server"/>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MarkupRxv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg" ValidationExpression="^(-)?\d+(\.\d\d)?$" ForeColor="Red">
                            #.#</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="MarkupRfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg" ForeColor="Red">
                            *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="AddBtn" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnClick="AddBtn_Click" CommandArgument="EmptyData" CausesValidation="true"
                             ValidationGroup="NewRowVg"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" Visible="false" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="NameLbl" runat="server" Text="<%# Item.Name %>" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NameTxt" runat="server" Text="<%# Item.Name %>" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NameTxt" ValidationGroup="EditRowVg" ForeColor="Red">
                        *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NameTxt" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NameTxt" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg" ForeColor="Red">
                        *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Markup">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="MarkupLbl" runat="server" Text="<%# Item.Markup %>" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="MarkupTxt" runat="server" Text="<%# Item.Markup %>"/>
                    <%--<asp:RangeValidator ID="MarkupRngv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="EditRowVg" Type="Double"
                        MaximumValue="999.9999" MinimumValue="-999.9999" ForeColor="Red">
                        #.##</asp:RangeValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MarkupRxv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="EditRowVg" ValidationExpression="^(-)?\d+(\.\d\d)?$" ForeColor="Red">
                        #.#</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="MarkupRfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="EditRowVg" ForeColor="Red">
                        *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="MarkupTxt" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="MarkupRngv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg"  Type="Double"
                        MaximumValue="999.9999" MinimumValue="-999.9999" ForeColor="Red">
                        #.##</asp:RangeValidator>
                    <%-- <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MarkupRxv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg" 
                        ValidationExpression="^(-)?\d+(\.\d\d)?$" ForeColor="Red">
                        #.#</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="MarkupRfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MarkupTxt" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg" ForeColor="Red">
                        *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="EditRowVg" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton id="AddBtn" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnClick="AddBtn_Click" CommandArgument="NotEmpty" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="NewRowVg" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="PriceGroupEds" runat="server" EnableInsert="true" EnableDelete="true" EnableFlattening="false" EnableUpdate="true" EntitySetName="PricingGroups"
        ConnectionString="name=Entities" DefaultContainerName="Entities" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
    protected void PriceGroupGv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (sender as GridView).Rows[e.RowIndex];
        e.NewValues["Name"] = (gvr.FindControl("NameTxt") as TextBox).Text;
        e.NewValues["Markup"] = Decimal.Parse((gvr.FindControl("MarkupTxt") as TextBox).Text);

        PriceGroupGv.DataBind();
    }// end event
```

Comment: Try dumping that value into a temporary variable within PriceGroupGv_RowUpdating.  Then insert a breakpoint, and check what that variable gets.  Maybe do the same thing with the value of MarkupTxt, just to see how it looks.

Comment: the values come through but 0 still does not get updated to the database.  The values go regardless if I pass them as string or decimal types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED - made the Markup column Nullable in the database and model. I also changed the type to Float in the db and Double in the model, but what finally got it working was having the nullable property.

If anybody else has a better solution I'll welcome any other answers.